# Mac OS X - access files owned by system

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, file-permissions

How can I access folders with those permissions?

[image: Folder Info]

When trying through terminal:

```
superUser99:tmp superUser99$ cd launchd
-bash: cd: launchd: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sudo -s` to open a root shell, then `cd` into the directory and do things there (still as root):

```
$ cd /private/var/tmp
$ sudo -s
Password:
# cd launchd        # Now running as root; note the changed command prompt
# ls -l
total 0
srwx------  1 root  wheel  0 Mar 24 20:46 sock
# exit        # This exits the root shell, taking me back to normal
$
```

Note that you should be very very careful while executing commands as root. It is quite easy to break OS X horribly with a small mistake plus root access...